# MacBook keeps booting into Linux even if I press Option key

Tags: mac, unix

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 13-inch (no touch bar) that does not let me boot into macOS.

I tried these few key combinations: <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, and it still does not work.

Comment: Is Linux the only bootable system available?

Comment: I don't know I tried to boot it to recovery but it goes to grub menu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. macOS Recovery is a built-in recovery system that should work even if Linux is installed. Make sure you press and hold Option-Command-R **immediately** after starting up your Mac. That key combination will start macOS Recovery over the internet. see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac for details.